# database program written in lazarus

Tags: database, pascal, lazarus

Hi i need to write some Graphic interace program that allow keeping, finding and adding data about some topic (something like database). Here is a example (zoo manager) http://imageshack.us/a/img96/5070/prog2projekt.png.
I have never working on that kind of preject before ?
Does anyone has some simmilar program with source code ? It would be very helpful to me.
Thanks

Comment: There are several articles and tutorials about DB programming with Lazarus: [http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Databases](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Databases). You also can find some code in the `/lazarus/examples/database` directory.

Comment: @Abelisto, good advice, why don't you write that down as an answer?

Comment: @reiniero Just because this is not actually answer, but it is just links to possible answers.